# Custom ArrayAdapters keep failing to launch

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

```
    package com.test.ExampleListview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
                "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
                "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("created arraylist");

        final ButtonArrayAdapter adapter = new ButtonArrayAdapter(this,
                values);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        System.out.println("created adapter and set it");

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                list.remove(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}

package com.test.ExampleListview;

/**
 * Created by User on 17/06/13.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ButtonArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public ButtonArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttontext);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonimage);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cool);
        return rowView;
    }
}


06-07 12:58:43.874 15319-15319/com.test.ExampleListview D/MyActivity: index=2 
06-07 12:58:43.924 15319-15319/com.test.ExampleListview D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM   
06-07 12:58:43.924 15319-15319/com.test.ExampleListview W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread    
exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 
06-07 12:58:43.944 15319-15319/com.test.ExampleListview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:  
main java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.test.ExampleListview.ButtonArrayAdapter.getView(ButtonArrayAdapter.java:31)`
```

I have followed a tutorial online and it has really helped for the basics of ArrayAdapters.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

However when I try to use a custom ArrayAdapter the application gives no compile errors but fails to launch. I was wondering am I doing anything obviously wrong, I have spent several hours testing things and I fear my rudimentary amount of Android knowledge means I'm missing something obvious. I can't even find my println in logcat! I don't think its doing anything but crashing immediately...

Thanks.

Comment: we can't help you without any log output. also, use `Log.d` instead of `System.out.println()`

Comment: Thanks,
'06-07 12:58:43.874  15319-15319/com.test.ExampleListview       D/MyActivity: index=2
06-07 12:58:43.924  15319-15319/com.test.ExampleListview       D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-07 12:58:43.924  15319-15319/com.test.ExampleListview       W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-07 12:58:43.944  15319-15319/com.test.ExampleListview       E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.test.ExampleListview.ButtonArrayAdapter.getView(ButtonArrayAdapter.java:31)'

Comment: so it's throwing a null pointer at this line in the custom adapter

`textView.setText(values[position])`

Comment: mind posting `rowlayout.xml` ?

Comment: Would it be anything to do with my rowlayout?

Android studio says my "Namespace is unbound"?

`<?xml

 version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/rowlayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@+id/buttontext"
                android:drawableLeft="@+id/buttonimage"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical">
</RelativeLayout>`

Look below for a better formatted one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these rows:

```
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttontext);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonimage);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
```

You're getting a NPE at textView. so probably textView refers to an invalid object. That means `rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttontext)` is failing. Check every name or field in your xml file and probably the bug will show clearly. 
If you still have issues, post here your files content.

Comment: I have a file called `rowlayout.xml`

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/rowlayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@+id/buttontext"
                android:drawableLeft="@+id/buttonimage"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical">
</RelativeLayout>`

I also have a `mainactivity.xml` that holds a listview for it... I'm not seeing anything here...

Answer (score 0):

In this code block:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttontext);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonimage);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cool);
        return rowView;
}
```

Try the following:

- Make sure all the ids you reference are set in the XML that you inflate.
- Make sure that `values != null` is true.
- Use `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);` for readability.
- Use `View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, false)` (null parent). The list will add the view by itself.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately I did all you things and it still has the same error. Maybe it's something in my xml file... rowlayout

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/rowlayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@+id/buttontext"
                android:drawableLeft="@+id/buttonimage"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical">
</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

Would it be anything to do with my rowlayout?

Android studio says my "Namespace is unbound"?

```
<?xml

 version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/rowlayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@+id/buttontext"
                android:drawableLeft="@+id/buttonimage"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical">
</RelativeLayout>
```